# Flutter SFDataGrid display the row details in a separate screen instead of Alert Box

Tags: flutter, syncfusion, flutter-datatable, sfdatagrid

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:syncfusion_flutter_datagrid/datagrid.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(primarySwatch: Colors.blue),
      home: const SfDataGridDemo()));
}

class SfDataGridDemo extends StatefulWidget {
  const SfDataGridDemo({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  SfDataGridDemoState createState() => SfDataGridDemoState();
}

class SfDataGridDemoState extends State<SfDataGridDemo> {
  late EmployeeDataSource _employeeDataSource;
  List<Employee> _employees = <Employee>[];

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _employees = getEmployeeData();
    _employeeDataSource = EmployeeDataSource(_employees);
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: const Text('Flutter SfDataGrid'),
        ),
        body: SfDataGrid(
            source: _employeeDataSource,
            columns: getColumns,
            columnWidthMode: ColumnWidthMode.fill,
            onCellTap: ((details) {
              if (details.rowColumnIndex.rowIndex != 0) {
                int selectedRowIndex = details.rowColumnIndex.rowIndex - 1;
                var row = _employeeDataSource.effectiveRows
                    .elementAt(selectedRowIndex);

                showDialog(
                    context: context,
                    builder: (context) => AlertDialog(
                        shape: const RoundedRectangleBorder(
                            borderRadius:
                                BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(32.0))),
                        content: SizedBox(
                          height: 200,
                          width: 200,
                          child: Column(
                              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
                              children: [
                                Text(
                                    'ID: ${row.getCells()[0].value.toString()}'),
                                Text(
                                    'Name: ${row.getCells()[1].value.toString()}'),
                                Text(
                                    'Designation: ${row.getCells()[2].value.toString()}'),
                                Text(
                                    'Salary: ${row.getCells()[3].value.t`your text`oString()}'),
                                SizedBox(
                                    width: 200,
                                    child: ElevatedButton(
                                        onPressed: () {
                                          Navigator.pop(context);
                                        },
                                        child: const Text("OK"))),
                              ]),
                        )));
              }
            })));
  }

  List<GridColumn> get getColumns {
    return [
      GridColumn(
          columnName: 'id',
          label: Container(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 8.0),
              alignment: Alignment.center,
              child: const Text(
                'ID',
                overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
              ))),
      GridColumn(
          columnName: 'name',
          label: Container(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 8.0),
              alignment: Alignment.center,
              child: const Text('Name', overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis))),
      GridColumn(
          columnName: 'designation',
          label: Container(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 8.0),
              alignment: Alignment.center,
              child:
                  const Text('Designation', overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis))),
      GridColumn(
          columnName: 'salary',
          label: Container(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 8.0),
              alignment: Alignment.center,
              child: const Text('Salary', overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis)))
    ];
  }

  List<Employee> getEmployeeData() {
    return [
      Employee(10001, 'James', 'Project Lead', 70000),
      Employee(10002, 'Kathryn', 'Manager', 99000),
      Employee(10003, 'Lara', 'Developer', 33000),
      Employee(10004, 'Michael', 'Designer', 35000),
      Employee(10005, 'Martin', 'Developer', 45000),
      Employee(10006, 'Newberry', 'Developer', 29000),
      Employee(10007, 'Balnc', 'Designer', 33000),
      Employee(10008, 'Perry', 'Developer', 31000),
      Employee(10009, 'Gable', 'Developer', 29500),
      Employee(10010, 'Grimes', 'Developer', 28000)
    ];
  }
}

class EmployeeDataSource extends DataGridSource {
  EmployeeDataSource(List<Employee> employees) {
    buildDataGridRow(employees);
  }

  void buildDataGridRow(List<Employee> employeeData) {
    dataGridRow = employeeData.map<DataGridRow>((employee) {
      return DataGridRow(cells: [
        DataGridCell<int>(columnName: 'id', value: employee.id),
        DataGridCell<String>(columnName: 'name', value: employee.name),
        DataGridCell<String>(
            columnName: 'designation', value: employee.designation),
        DataGridCell<int>(columnName: 'salary', value: employee.salary),
      ]);
    }).toList();
  }

  List<DataGridRow> dataGridRow = <DataGridRow>[];

  @override
  List<DataGridRow> get rows => dataGridRow.isEmpty ? [] : dataGridRow;

  @override
  DataGridRowAdapter? buildRow(DataGridRow row) {
    return DataGridRowAdapter(
        cells: row.getCells().map<Widget>((dataGridCell) {
      return Container(
        alignment: Alignment.center,
        padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 8.0),
        child: Text(dataGridCell.value.toString()),
      );
    }).toList());
  }
}

class Employee {
  Employee(this.id, this.name, this.designation, this.salary);
  final int id;
  final String name;
  final String designation;
  final int salary;
}
```

I'm using the above code to display the row details in a alert box.

The problem is that on a table selection I want the page to navigate to a detail page and show the details in a separate page.

I don't know how I can pass the data snapshot to the detail page when row is selected.
I am using Syncfusion Flutter Datagrid example to implement this feature. Any answers might help.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
    onCellTap: ((details) {
      if (details.rowColumnIndex.rowIndex != 0) {
        int selectedRowIndex = details.rowColumnIndex.rowIndex - 1;
        var row = _employeeDataSource.effectiveRows.elementAt(selectedRowIndex);

        // Uncomment if you need a transition when tapping on a line
        /*Navigator.push(
              context,
              MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => DataView(row: row)),
          );*/

        showDialog(
          context: context,
          builder: (context) => AlertDialog(
            shape: const RoundedRectangleBorder(
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(32.0))),
            content: SizedBox(
              height: 200,
              width: 200,
              child: Column(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
                children: [
                  Text('ID: ${row.getCells()[0].value.toString()}'),
                  Text('Name: ${row.getCells()[1].value.toString()}'),
                  Text('Designation: ${row.getCells()[2].value.toString()}'),
                  Text('Salary: ${row.getCells()[3].value.toString()}'),
                  SizedBox(
                    width: 200,
                    child: ElevatedButton(
                      onPressed: () {
                        // Open a new page when you click on the button
                        Navigator.push(
                          context,
                          MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => DataView(row: row)),
                        );
                      },
                      child: const Text("OK"),
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
        );
      }
    }),
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

To navigate between pages in your Flutter application, you can utilize the **Navigator** widget. You can push a new page onto the navigation stack using the Navigator.push method, providing the context and the desired page to navigate to. The type of transition animation used when navigating can be specified using the MaterialPageRoute. By passing the **DataGridRow** to the **DetailsPage** widget, the details from that row can be retrieved for display. For further clarification, refer to the following sample.

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:syncfusion_flutter_datagrid/datagrid.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(primarySwatch: Colors.blue),
      home: const SfDataGridDemo()));
}

class SfDataGridDemo extends StatefulWidget {
  const SfDataGridDemo({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  SfDataGridDemoState createState() => SfDataGridDemoState();
}

class SfDataGridDemoState extends State<SfDataGridDemo> {
  late EmployeeDataSource _employeeDataSource;
  List<Employee> _employees = <Employee>[];

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _employees = getEmployeeData();
    _employeeDataSource = EmployeeDataSource(_employees);
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text('Flutter SfDataGrid'),
      ),
      body: SfDataGrid(
        source: _employeeDataSource,
        columns: getColumns,
        columnWidthMode: ColumnWidthMode.fill,
        onCellTap: ((details) {
          if (details.rowColumnIndex.rowIndex != 0) {
            int selectedRowIndex = details.rowColumnIndex.rowIndex - 1;
            var row =
                _employeeDataSource.effectiveRows.elementAt(selectedRowIndex);
            Navigator.push(
                context,
                MaterialPageRoute(
                    builder: (context) => DetailsPage(dataGridRow: row)));
          }
        }),
      ),
    );
  }

  List<GridColumn> get getColumns {
    return [
      GridColumn(
          columnName: 'id',
          label: Container(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 8.0),
              alignment: Alignment.center,
              child: const Text(
                'ID',
                overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
              ))),
      GridColumn(
          columnName: 'name',
          label: Container(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 8.0),
              alignment: Alignment.center,
              child: const Text('Name', overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis))),
      GridColumn(
          columnName: 'designation',
          label: Container(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 8.0),
              alignment: Alignment.center,
              child:
                  const Text('Designation', overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis))),
      GridColumn(
          columnName: 'salary',
          label: Container(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 8.0),
              alignment: Alignment.center,
              child: const Text('Salary', overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis)))
    ];
  }

  List<Employee> getEmployeeData() {
    return [
      Employee(10001, 'James', 'Project Lead', 70000),
      Employee(10002, 'Kathryn', 'Manager', 99000),
      Employee(10003, 'Lara', 'Developer', 33000),
      Employee(10004, 'Michael', 'Designer', 35000),
      Employee(10005, 'Martin', 'Developer', 45000),
      Employee(10006, 'Newberry', 'Developer', 29000),
      Employee(10007, 'Balnc', 'Designer', 33000),
      Employee(10008, 'Perry', 'Developer', 31000),
      Employee(10009, 'Gable', 'Developer', 29500),
      Employee(10010, 'Grimes', 'Developer', 28000)
    ];
  }
}

class EmployeeDataSource extends DataGridSource {
  EmployeeDataSource(List<Employee> employees) {
    buildDataGridRow(employees);
  }

  void buildDataGridRow(List<Employee> employeeData) {
    dataGridRow = employeeData.map<DataGridRow>((employee) {
      return DataGridRow(cells: [
        DataGridCell<int>(columnName: 'id', value: employee.id),
        DataGridCell<String>(columnName: 'name', value: employee.name),
        DataGridCell<String>(
            columnName: 'designation', value: employee.designation),
        DataGridCell<int>(columnName: 'salary', value: employee.salary),
      ]);
    }).toList();
  }

  List<DataGridRow> dataGridRow = <DataGridRow>[];

  @override
  List<DataGridRow> get rows => dataGridRow.isEmpty ? [] : dataGridRow;

  @override
  DataGridRowAdapter? buildRow(DataGridRow row) {
    return DataGridRowAdapter(
        cells: row.getCells().map<Widget>((dataGridCell) {
      return Container(
        alignment: Alignment.center,
        padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 8.0),
        child: Text(dataGridCell.value.toString()),
      );
    }).toList());
  }
}

class DetailsPage extends StatefulWidget {
  const DetailsPage({
    super.key,
    required this.dataGridRow,
  });
  final DataGridRow dataGridRow;
  @override
  State<DetailsPage> createState() => DetailsPageState();
}

class DetailsPageState extends State<DetailsPage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(title: const Text('Details Page')),
        body: Center(
          child: SizedBox(
            height: 200,
            width: 200,
            child: Column(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                children: [
                  Text(
                      'ID: ${widget.dataGridRow.getCells()[0].value.toString()}'),
                  Text(
                      'Name: ${widget.dataGridRow.getCells()[1].value.toString()}'),
                  Text(
                      'Designation: ${widget.dataGridRow.getCells()[2].value.toString()}'),
                  Text(
                      'Salary: ${widget.dataGridRow.getCells()[3].value.toString()}'),
                ]),
          ),
        ));
  }
}

class Employee {
  Employee(this.id, this.name, this.designation, this.salary);
  final int id;
  final String name;
  final String designation;
  final int salary;
}
```